# JS Form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a large form that needs a single function to validate the whole form.

My form name is "orderform"  I have everything set up in the form end correctly now I just need to add to the function.

I need to make sure the email address is entered and valid, in the form it's called "emailaddress" what do I need to include in the function so this happens?

Also, I have 2 radio buttons and I need it so that when one is selected nothing happens but when the other one is selected it validates another section, for example other address.

Could anyone lend a hand?

oh, last thing, must be simple but how can you validate a number field and also make sure it's of a certain length, for example, postcode.

Thanks everyone!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common thing to do. Have you checked any JS validation plugins or frameworks? Most of them already have common validation patterns like required fields, numbers, email addresses, etc.

[jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) has built in validator for email address, numners, URL. It also allows you to add your own validators.

I've seen a lost of websites where validator does not accept my e-mail address with "INFO" TLD. A regex to validate an e-mail address is not that simple. Here is an extract from jQuery Validator:

```
/**
 * jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0
 *
 * http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
 * http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 - 2011 JÃ¶rn Zaefferer
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email
    email: function(value, element) {
        // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
        return this.optional(element) || /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i.test(value);
    },
```

Comment: I have to do it all by code and locally on my machine, I'm learning you see. Sorry should've made it clearer, my bad.

Comment: Well, it might be OK for learning, but I would always investigate list of available libraries and tools before reinventing the bicycle. Consider all the time you will loose to test and fixed your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can access information inside forms using:

`document.yourformname.elementname`

To see how to validate them, [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html) has a really excellent introduction, including the radio and checkboxes you'll need.  Form validation is kind of too big to answer in one post. ;)